# mvn clean Vs mvn clean install

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-install-plugin

I have some third-party jar dependency. So, I have used maven-install-plugin to install these third party jar to my local repository(.m2/repository). This plugin is bound to clean phase. When i do **"mvn clean install"**, before running clean , its starts searching for dependency and ultimately the build fails since it fails to find third party jar. But when i run mvn clean separately , it installs the file in local repository. Subsequently when i run mvn clean install, which builds successfully. Is mvn clean + mvn install != mvn clean install ?

Answer (score 2):

Maven defined 3 **independent** build lifecycles: *build*, *clean*, and *site*.

`mvn clean install` runs 2 of them.

`mvn clean` and later `mvn install` should run them one after the other.

It may take a bit more time to execute (since maven needs to start twice) - but the results should be the same.

Please note the `validate` step happens only on the `build` cycle - and not on the `clean` cycle.

[image]

Comment: All this is fine, but i fail to understand why mvn clean deosn't check for dependency but mvn clean install does(before running the clean itself)

Comment: This is likely to be due to the `validate` phase that exists only on the "build" flow - where "install" is a step.